# How to use a column value based on another column value in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a table using case statements. Below is my query. It returns an empty table

```
select 
  CASE
    WHEN org_comm.CommQualifier ='FX' THEN org_comm.CommPhone
    WHEN pers_comm.CommQualifier='FX' THEN pers_comm.CommPhone
END
  AS FAX,
  from `project.database.table`,
UNNEST(ServiceBusEnvelope.Payload.RepairOrderFolderAddRq.RepairOrderHeader.AdminInfo.Owner.Party.OrgInfo.Communications) AS org_comm, 
UNNEST(ServiceBusEnvelope.Payload.RepairOrderFolderAddRq.RepairOrderHeader.AdminInfo.Owner.Party.Personinfo.Communications) AS pers_comm;
```

Please help me find the reason for the empty results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CASE ... WHEN ...` is just fine. You can see it works as expected with sample data below. You should check your data source.

```sql
WITH data AS (
    SELECT STRUCT<CommQualifier STRING, CommPhone STRING>('FX', '1234') org_comm,
           STRUCT<CommQualifier STRING, CommPhone STRING>('YY', '5678') pers_comm
    UNION ALL
    SELECT STRUCT<CommQualifier STRING, CommPhone STRING>('ZZ', '1234') org_comm,
           STRUCT<CommQualifier STRING, CommPhone STRING>('FX', '5678') pers_comm
) 
select 
  CASE
    WHEN org_comm.CommQualifier ='FX' THEN org_comm.CommPhone
    WHEN pers_comm.CommQualifier='FX' THEN pers_comm.CommPhone
END
  AS FAX,
  from data
```

Output:

```
+------+
| FAX  |
+------+
| 1234 |
| 5678 |
+------+
```